# Need help identifying a sound effect

Tags: sound-effects, sample

So there's a sound effect that I can't seem to identify. I thought i'd ask for help here.

[Here it is.](https://clyp.it/cbj5vtjr)

That sound effect is also used throughout [Rom di Prisco's Trition track from the NFS3:HS soundtrack, for musical reference.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4NlVB2gPqes)

Answer (score 1):

That's a metallic-striking sound, probably a pitch-lowered ride cymbal used in many a track for many a year to convey some level of tension. Usually as a single, unobstructed strike at the end of a chord pattern or drum sequence.

It also has a lot of large room reverb, which helps to define it as a large, tense, important sound.

Beautiful, robust sound and easily reproduced if you have the right type of ride cymbal sample to start.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something from a doom game or a crashing tie fighter, so probably a mix of lion, hyena and f22 jet! :D
Have you tried playing it at different speeds? would say faster and you might get the original sound.